# getting a error log in php nginx server used with sendy in aws RDS servers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, sendy

I am using sendy email sending script in aws ec2 instance with database based on aws rds services and it is connected with it as well. My issue is that whenever sendy runs and it tries to send email which is running on ec2 instance it gives me a 504 gateway time out issue. When checking the logs this is the error message I am getting in nginx error log messages

```
2021/04/19 06:28:57 [alert] 30748#30748: *109381 open socket #14 left in connection 18
2021/04/19 06:28:57 [alert] 30748#30748: *109379 open socket #7 left in connection 19
2021/04/19 06:28:57 [alert] 30748#30748: *109380 open socket #13 left in connection 23
2021/04/19 06:28:57 [alert] 30748#30748: *109378 open socket #3 left in connection 24
2021/04/19 06:28:57 [alert] 30748#30748: aborting
```

what I am able to get the idea here that nginx tries to restart itself everytime we start sending emails. How to resolve this issue as it is hampering our production servers.

Would be great if you could resolve it. Remember here is no code issue. It is more of server configuration issue. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send your problem to the sendy support section so that they can help you, and the second way is that you can use another server to send email or even write it yourself. You can with PHP Build a robot that will send you an email. I hope this article is useful for you, and if you do a Google search, it will teach you how to build it.

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time on it but I asked on it sendy forum as well. No response as of yet now. I will keep you posted though if get it resolved. Upvoting for your time!